# Highlighting lines in different colors in SyntaxHighlighter

Tags: javascript, css, syntaxhighlighter

In [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/), is it possible to [highlight lines](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/highlight.html) with different colors (say, some lines in green, some other in blue)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know SyntaxHighlighter, but looking at the site it would appear that you can highlight with a single colour, but there's nothing to allow you to use multiple highlight colours.

The only thing I can suggest is to contact the author and suggest it as a feature request.

Answer (score 4):

Like @MatTheCat said, change the background-color on the class alt1 and/or alt2

```
.syntaxhighlighter .line.alt1 {
    background-color: white !important;
}
.syntaxhighlighter .line.alt2 {
   background-color: #F8F8F8 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each line is a  with a class which shows the line number () so apply a background-color to the right class.

Answer (score 0):

The version 3.0.83 supports highlighting of certain lines. See http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/highlight.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre class="brush: php; html-script: true; highlight: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]">
     line 1
     line 2
     line 3
     line 4
     line 5
     line 6
</pre>
```

this will highlight line 1 to 6. Check Documentation: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/highlight.html